# Focus method triggers button click event

Tags: javascript, html

i have a div with keydown handler and button with click handler, in that keydown handler i am focusing a button with focus() method, but it triggers btn click handler. please tell why this happens

Note: press enter key on div

```js
function btnclick() {
  console.log('button click triggered');
}

function btnKeyDown() {
  console.log('key down triggered');
  document.getElementById('btn1').focus();
}
```

```html
<div id='btn' onkeydown="btnKeyDown()" tabindex='0'>Click1</div>
<button id='btn1' onclick="btnclick()">Click Me!2</button>
```

Comment: It only happens when you press Return, not any key.

Comment: I think it happens when you press enter because after you focus the button, the default event handler for `keydown` will run on the now focused button, if you pass the event and call `e.preventDefault()` it should prevent that.

Comment: yes i am pressing enter key

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This strange behavior only happens when you press the <kbd>Return</kbd> key. Pressing Return while focus is on an element is equivalent to clicking on it. So when you change the focus, the default action is performed on the newly focused element, not the original one.

Calling `event.preventDefault()` prevents this from happening.

```js
function btnclick() {
  console.log('button click triggered');
}

function btnKeyDown(event) {
  console.log('key down triggered');
  document.getElementById('btn1').focus();
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<div id='btn' onkeydown="btnKeyDown(event)" tabindex='0'>Click1</div>
<button id='btn1' onclick="btnclick()">Click Me!2</button>
```

Comment: That is — not — quite right. It triggers both `events`. How is that happening? I guess a `.one()` with jQuery does help. %)P

Comment: I was able to bypass this behavior by using the keyup rather than keydown event (presumably because the "click" event has already fired once keyup fires).

Answer (score 0):

Because when you click the button it is clicking it. Key down is for keyboard. While we call what you made a button, it is not the button referred to when it says "onkeydown".

Barmar is also correct about the enter key. If that is the key you are using it would also trigger the onclick event.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `onkeydown` you need to use `onfocus` which will work on every browser

```js
function btnclick() {
  console.log('button click triggered');
}

function btnKeyDown() {
  console.log('key down triggered');
  document.getElementById('btn1').focus();
 alert('key down triggered' +  document.getElementById('btn1').innerText);
  
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txtVal" onfocus="btnKeyDown()" >
<div id='btn' onfocus="btnKeyDown()" tabindex='0'>Click1</div>
<button id='btn1' onclick="btnclick()">Click Me!2</button>
```