# Wrong keydown listener is called with `.focus`

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

I am making a library for data grid keyboard navigation, and noticed a really weird behaviour that is consistent across the browsers and not sure why this is happening.

So the issue is with the current flow:

1. Click on the parent div, there is a handler to focus on it when clicked
2. Press `Enter` key, and it will programmatically focus on the nested `button`

(Below is the part that is not supposed to happen)

3. There is a `keydown` and `click` listener attached to the button. With the previous `Enter` stroke, the button's `click` listener is being triggered, while I would guess it shouldn't be.

The example in the attached snippet is flaky not sure why, be sure to test also in [JSfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/3z7nfgtw/82/)

Any clue why this is happening?

```js
document.getElementById("child-action").addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if(e.currentTarget !== e.target) return;
    console.log(e);
  alert("Child click pressed")
})

document.getElementById("parent-cell").addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  console.log("Key down in parent, focusing on child....");
  const child = document.getElementById("child-action").focus();
})

document.getElementById("parent-cell").addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  console.log("Clicking parent, focusing on parent....");
  e.target.focus();
})

document.getElementById("child-action").addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  alert("Child key pressed")
  console.log(e);
})
```

```css
#parent-cell {
  width: 350px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: pink;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#child-action {
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: gray;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}


div:focus,
button:focus {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent-cell" tabindex="0">
  Click here to start focusing
 <button type="button" id="child-action" tabindex="0">
   Hey there
 </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you considered adding some event propagation controls, like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopImmediatePropagation

Comment: You're changing focus on `keydown` but `click` fires later on the matching `keyup` so the `currentTarget` and `target` is the button at the time `click` fires, leading to your condition `e.currentTarget !== e.target` returning false

Comment: @Kinglish even if you add them it does not work. You can test this in JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3z7nfgtw/84/

Comment: @pilchard I know this, and this is exactly my question. Why this is happening. Why there is a `click` firing with no click, while pressing `Enter` in a parent? Also the event propagation, in my mind would be bottom-up, in the Bubble phase, so I wouldn't expect to be triggered at all.

Comment: I found a similar question about the Enter.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50403457/focus-method-triggers-button-click-event

Comment: this is really weird, it seems you have to `e.preventDefault()`, in the parent click event callback  before you focus other element.